# How to assign indexes to values ​in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I built a linked list which displays the arguments passed on the command line, in the form of an int.

In order to do a sort later, I would like to assign indexes to each value of my list in an ordered way.

For example ./a.out -14  12  5  24
Assigned indexes :  [1] [3] [2] [4]

It's a school homework that consists of indexing each value stacked on stack A, sending them to stack B in order to sort them and sending them back sorted on stack A.

The index is an int variable defined in each of the nodes because I will later use it to identify the nodes by these indexes rather than by their values ​​themselves (easier to manage)

Do you have any idea how to proceed?

Here is my code for now

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct s_list   t_list;

struct  s_list
{
    int     value;
    int     index;
    t_list  *next;
};

void    add_node_start(t_list **head, int value);
void    add_node_end(t_list **head, int value);
int     remove_first(t_list **head);
int     remove_last(t_list *head);
int     remove_by_index(t_list **head, int n);
void    print_list(t_list *head);
int     ft_atoi(const char *str);

void    add_node_start(t_list **head, int value)
{
    t_list  *new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(t_list));
    
    new->value = value;
    new->next = *head;
    *head = new;
}

void    add_node_end(t_list **head, int value)
{
    t_list  *current;
    current = *head;
    
    if (!*head)
    {
        add_node_start(head, value);
        return ;
    }
    
    while (current->next != NULL)
        current = current->next;
    
    current->next = malloc(sizeof(t_list));
    current->next->value = value;
    current->next->next = NULL;
}

int remove_first(t_list **head)
{
    t_list  *next_node;
    int     retvalue;
    
    retvalue = -1;
    next_node = NULL;
    
    if (*head == NULL)
        return (-1);
    
    next_node = (*head)->next;
    retvalue = (*head)->value;
    free(*head);
    *head = next_node;

    return (retvalue);
}

int remove_last(t_list *head)
{
    t_list  *current;
    int     retvalue;

    retvalue = 0;

    if (head->next == NULL)
    {
        retvalue = head->value;
        free(head);
        return (retvalue);
    }
    
    current = head;
    while (current->next->next != NULL)
        current = current->next;

    retvalue = current->next->value;
    free(current->next);
    current->next = NULL;
    
    return(retvalue);
} 

int remove_by_index(t_list **head, int n)
{
    t_list  *current;
    t_list  *temp_node;
    int retvalue;
    int i;
    
    current = *head;
    i = 0;
    retvalue = -1;
    
    if (n == 0)
        return (remove_first(head));
    
    while (i < n - 1)
    {
        if (current->next == NULL)
            return (-1);
        current = current->next;
        i++;
    }
    temp_node = current->next;
    retvalue = temp_node->value;
    current->next = temp_node->next;
    free(temp_node);

    return(retvalue);
}

void    print_list(t_list *head)
{
    t_list  *current;
    current = head;
    
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", current->value);
        current = current->next;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    t_list  *head;
    int     i;
    head = NULL;
    
    i = 1;
    
    while (i < argc)
    {
        add_node_end(&head, ft_atoi(argv[i]));
        i++;
    }
    print_list(head);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: A linked list has no concept of indices. You will have to make the index information part of the payload

Comment: The index variable is an int located in my list structure

Comment: The concept of Index in Linked List does not exist explicitly as the one element points to another and so on. So Indexing in Linked list wont help in sorting too even if you add it. So If you require indexing in linked list then store object containing index and value rather than just value. I am writing this in Java perspective but concept should be similar.

Comment: You don't have any sorting code. How are you planning to calculate the sort index associated with each supplied value unless the values are sorted?

Comment: It's a school homework that consists of indexing each value stacked on stack A, sending them to stack B in order to sort them and sending them back sorted on stack A. The index is an int type variable defined in each of the nodes because I will later use it to identify the nodes by these indexes rather than by their values ​​themselves (easier to manage)

Comment: The point is that in order to assign the index values, you need to sort the values. How otherwise are you going to determine the index values? Also, you just introduced the notion of a 'stack' in your update. That word has a specific meaning in programming, related to a specific data structure. Do you mean it in that sense? There are no stacks in your code.

Comment: Is the index going to be just another part of the element contents that "sticks" to the same data value even after sorting? If so, you could do one of the following: (1) supply the desired index value to the function that adds an element to the list; or (2) call a function that (re)indexes the list after all the data has been added.

Answer (score 0):

"Indexes" for a linked list depends on the number of nodes in the list. It should not be a property of the nodes themselves but rather just plain counting up from the list head until the end.

So to get the node with "index" `n`, just use a simple `for` loop like:

```
t_list *current_node = head;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < n && current_node != NULL; ++i)
{
    current_node = current_node->next;
}
```

When the loop ends, `current_node` will either be null pointer (because `n` was larger than the number of nodes in the list) or it will be the node at "index" `n`.

Comment: It's a school homework that consists of indexing each value stacked on stack A, sending them to stack B in order to sort them and sending them back sorted on stack A.

The index is an int type variable defined in each of the nodes because I will later use it to identify the nodes by these indexes rather than by their values ​​themselves (easier to manage)

Comment: @Itsme Then I would rather call the "index" a *key*, and that you map a specific key to a specific node. The key needs to stay exactly the same, no matter the order of the node inside the list.

Comment: @Itsme I would also recommend that you separate the list and the node structures and functions. Like have a structure containing the head and tail pointers (the tail to make it easier to add to the end), keep track of the size, and also have a member for "next key" to be set for the next node to be added to the list.